# Query procurar valor na Base de Dados

Tags: php, mysql

Quero mostrar os resultados obtidos num formulário mas ao guardar na BD não me guardou como `null` mas guardou assim:

Data: `0000-00-00` E Numero: `0`

Query tenho assim:

```
$sql = mysql_query ("Select *, Count(*) from tabela1, tabela2 where campo1 = 0 and campo2= '0000-00-00' and campo3 is Null and campo4......'")
```

Mas ele não me está a mostrar o resultado. Tenho algo mal no código?

Comment: Qual é o formato/type da coluna?

Comment: Coloque assim e veja se aparece algum erro `$sql = mysql_query('select....') or (die mysql_error())`

Comment: A data é em Date 
o numero é Int

Comment: @user3253195, já testou essa consulta direto no banco de dados?

Comment: COm o Mysql Error não me aparece nada.

Comment: Devo ter um erro na forma de pedir os valores. Porque na query da BD tambem mostra em branco.

Comment: Eu pedi para mostrar a data 0000-00-00 or null e mesmo assim nada.

    $sql = mysql_query ("Select *, Count(*) from tabela1, tabela2 where (campo1 = 0 or campo1 is NULL) and (campo2= '0000-00-00' or campo2 is NULL) and campo3 is Null and campo4......'")

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque exatamente a consulta que esta tentando executar.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12898/discussion-between-perdeu-and-user3253195)

Comment: @user3253195 Clica no [link para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12898/discussion-between-perdeu-and-user3253195) sugerido pelo _perdeu_ para visualizares mais informação para te podermos ajudar.

Comment: Se possível poste no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), vai facilitar para responder

Comment: Só para complementar na versão do PHP 5.5.x a extensão mysql está descontinuada. O PHP net recomenda o uso de MySqli ou PDO_MySql >"The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED >errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL >extensions." Fonte http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration55.deprecated.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na tua pergunta, estás a dar a indicação de que a dificuldade é na operação de inserir novas linhas na base de dados. Posterior a isso, tens uma consulta para recolher resultados e dás indicação que a consulta não está a funcionar como pretendido, vamos analisar:

- Como criar a tabela de forma a que as coisas funcionem como pretendes;
- Realizar inserção de dados;
- Recolher registos existentes.

## Criar a tabela

Como pretendes que as colunas com o nome `campo1` e `campo2` sejam `null` por defeito, tens que dar essa indicação na própria tabela:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Como podes verificar, estamos a indicar que o valor por defeito para a coluna `campo1` e `campo2` é `null`.

O código para criação da tabela seria:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela1` (
  `id` int(13) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campo1` int(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campo2` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

## Inserir resultados

Com a tabela devidamente preparada para aceitar `null` nas colunas `campo1` e `campo2`, a consulta de inserção seria:

```
INSERT INTO `tabela1` ( `id` , `campo1` , `campo2` )
VALUES (NULL , NULL , NULL);
```

Isto vai inserir na tabela uma linha tipo:

[image: Captura de Tela]

## Realizar consultas

Agora que a tabela está da forma pretendida, as consultas procurando por registos `null` já podem ser realizadas.

Consulta igual à que tens na pergunta, ou seja, a coluna `campo1` igual a `0` e a coluna `campo2` igual a `null` ou igual a `0000-00-00`:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tabela1`
WHERE `campo1` =0
AND (
`campo2` IS NULL
OR `campo2` = '0000-00-00'
)
```

Que nos devolve precisamente dois registos onde ambos estão com o valor na coluna `campo1` igual a `0` e o valor da coluna `campo2` igual a `NULL` no ID 1 e igual a `0000-00-00` no ID 3:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui resolver. 
Apesar de aparecer na base de dados 0000-00-00 na data eu coloquei assim: 
Agradeço a quem me ajudou :)

```
include("conectar.php");
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador WHERE AlvaraNumero = 0 
 AND(AlvaraValidade='' or AlvaraValidade is Null or AlvaraValidade='0000-00-00')
 AND (AlvaraAnexo='' or AlvaraAnexo is Null)
 AND AcidenteNumero = 0
 AND (AcidenteValidade='' or AcidenteValidade is Null or AcidenteValidade='0000-00-00')    
 AND (AcidenteAnexo='' or AcidenteAnexo is Null)
 AND SeguroNumero = 0
 AND (SeguroValidade='' or SeguroValidade is Null or SeguroValidade='0000-00-00' )
 AND (SeguroAnexo='' or SeguroAnexo is Null)
 AND InstaladorNumero = 0
 AND (InstaladorValidade='' or InstaladorValidade is Null or InstaladorValidade='0000-00-00')
 AND (InstaladorAnexo='' or InstaladorAnexo is Null) " ) or DIE( mysql_error());

 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
```

Answer (score 0):

Nomeie as tabelas para fazer mostar em qual tabela esta o campo você passa pelo "WHERE".

Ex:

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM tabela1 AS tbl1, tabela2 AS tbl2 WHERE tbl1.campo1 = 0 and tbl2.campo2= '0000-00-00' and tbl1.campo3 is Null and tbl2.campo4......'");
```

Comment: Eu só chamo uma tabela e ele mostra-me em branco.
Mas se eu fizer 
     select * from tabela1
Ele mostra-me os dados inseridos